# WURFL for Mobiles

Tags: asp.net

I am using below code in Application_Start event of Global.asax in ASP.NET MVC. WURFL for detection of Mobiles. Below code works for restriction of tables and ipads but not for Samsung Galaxy Tab greater than 10 inches.

```
     DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode()
     {
     ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("tablet",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
 || context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("ipad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check for all tablets you can query WURFL by

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public const String WurflDataFilePath = "~/App_Data/wurfl.zip";
    private void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wurflDataFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WurflDataFilePath);
        var wurflPatchFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WurflPatchFilePath);
        var configurer = new InMemoryConfigurer()
                 .MainFile(wurflDataFile)
        var manager = WURFLManagerBuilder.Build(configurer);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache[WurflManagerCacheKey] = manager;
    }
}

var device = WURFLManagerBuilder.Instance.GetDeviceForRequest(userAgent);
var is_tablet = device.GetCapability("is_tablet");

if (is_tablet == true) {
    // Show tablet site
} else {
    // Show desktop site
}
```