# Issue's in WURFL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the below code, we are restricting tablets to open mobile version and need to open desktop version(only smartphones to open mobile version). In this case WURFL is misfunctioning some times please let us know any problem in the code.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode()
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("tablet", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                || context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("android 2.2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("ipad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see WURFL being instantiated in this code.  Please reference:

[WURFL for Mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859187/wurfl-for-mobiles/26922137#26922137)